# setState of dynamic multidimensional object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a state like this.

```
     insetts: {
        cid: {
          checked: false,
          value: "",
        },
        name: {
          checked: false,
          value: "",
        },
...
     },
     outsetts: {
...
     },
...
```

the event handler will receive the name of each level and update the fields checked and value of the checked item.

(the outer level is accessed through props - this.props.which)
I need to update
const target = evt.target.value;
this.state[this.props.which][target].checked

How can I use setState?

I've tried:

```
this.setState({
  [this.props.which]: {
    ...this.state[this.props.which], 
      [evt.target.value]: {
        ...this.state[this.props.which][target], 
          checked: true
      }
    } 
  }
);
```

and some variants of it but to no avail.

Thanks

**EDITED**

it is working with the cloning approach recommended by @Vo Quoc Thang

```
const target = evt.target.value;
const cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state[this.props.which]));
cloned[target].checked = true;
```

and both of the following approaches:

```
this.setState((prevState) => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    [this.props.which]: cloned,
  };
});
```

or

```
this.setState({ ...this.state, [this.props.which]: cloned });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the object first, modify it and update to your state

```
const attr = this.props.which;
const cloned = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state[attr]));
cloned[evt.target.value].checked = true;
this.setState({attr : cloned});
```

Comment: Unexpected keyword 'this' in  `this.props.which : cloned});  `

Comment: @mehrlicht maybe it "this" keyword get lost in setState. I have edited my answer. pls check

Comment: I had already tried that. No error but does nothing to the state.

Comment: Maybe you have to provide more context to find your problem

Comment: OK. I was doing something wrong. It is working with the clone approach you recommended and with both of the alternatives I edited in the question. thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.